# ProGuard and dynamic proxies with spring 3

Tags: java, spring, proguard, proxies

i am trying to obfuscate a java app with ProGuard, but i have a problem with one particular topic, here it is.

My app uses Java 1.7, Valkyrie RCP for GUI, spring 3.1.3 for bean container and spring JDBC for database communication, so spring contains all objects, from gui views to jdbc's daos.

When i obfuscate the code with ProGuard 5.1, spring is having problems to instantiate beans. I am usging ant target, here is the code:

```xml
<proguard
          optimize="false"
          shrink="false"
          obfuscate="true"
          allowaccessmodification="false"
          usemixedcaseclassnames="false"
          skipnonpubliclibraryclasses="false"
          printseeds="obfuscateseeds.txt"
          printusage="obfuscateusage.txt"
          printmapping="obfuscatemapping.txt">

  <keepattribute name="*Annotation*"/>

  <injar name="${proj.output}/app/lib/myjar.jar"/>
  <outjar name="${proj.output}/app/lib/myjar-ofuscated.jar"/>

  <keep name="com.myjar.Main">
    <method name="main"/>
  </keep>

  <libraryjar name="${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar"/>
  ...

</proguard>
```

I have many configuration classes, and proguard ofuscate them very well, but at the moment some of them gets instantiated, a wrong method is called. For exame my main Configuration object is like next:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ RulesContext.class })
public class MainContext implements ApplicationConfig{

    @Autowired private RulesContext rulesContext;

    @Bean public AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect annotationBeanConfigurerAspect(){
        logger.debug("annotationBeanConfigurerAspect");

        return AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf();
    }

    /* lot of methods between */

    @Bean @Override public RulesSource rulesSource() {
        logger.debug("rulesSource");
        DefaultRulesSource rules = new DefaultRulesSource();
        rules.addRules(rulesContext.enterpriseRules());
        rules.addRules(rulesContext.coinRules());
        rules.addRules(rulesContext.bankRules());
    }

    /* lot of methods after */
}
```

when it gets obfuscated, the result is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({o.class})
public class b
  implements ApplicationConfig
{
  @Autowired
  private o f;

  @Bean
  public AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect a()
  {
    this.a.debug("annotationBeanConfigurerAspect");
    return AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf();
  }

  @Bean
  public RulesSource rulesSource()
  {
    this.a.debug("rulesSource");
    DefaultRulesSource localDefaultRulesSource = new DefaultRulesSource();
    localDefaultRulesSource.addRules(this.f.a());
    localDefaultRulesSource.addRules(this.f.b());
    localDefaultRulesSource.addRules(this.f.c());
  }
}
```

And when i exec the app, it throws an exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rulesSource' defined in class
>   com.myjar.j.b: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public org.valkyriercp.rules.RulesSource
>   com.myjar.j.b.rulesSource()] threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
>   cannot be cast to com.myjar.n.g.b.b

The object com.myjar.n.g.b.b (RulesContext before obfuscation) has a method a() which returns an appropiate RulesObject, but for some reason, method a() in the obfuscated RulesContext object does not gets invoked, but method a() in the b object (MainContext) instead. So method a() in b (MainContext) object returns an AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect object, which is not a Rules object and so the exception.

If i avoid obfuscation over the package which contains all spring config objects, the program runs very well, it is just obfuscation when the problem is present.

Any of you has encountered some similar problem? how do you solve it? or, any clue on what's happening?

Thank you for your time

Comment: similar problem... not really but with Proguard ( or any other obfuscation tool ) we often add lot's of excpetion to get it working... So yes it is a burden ( we use Proguard + old Tapestry and that is still error-prone ).

Comment: hehe, i think i have to live with it. My app has over 700 file class and just about 15 of them are spring config objects, so in any way this is a good obfuscation percent, it is just a little rock on my shoes.